# iOS Phonegap/Cordova HTML5/Youtube videos sound not working

Tags: cordova, phonegap, cordova-ios

I am trying to embed HTML5 video and Youtube Videos to my IOS Cordova App. It is showing the video but sound not working with iOS latest versions. Sound works fine on old iOS versions.

Is there anything needs to be updated in config.xml?

Thanks!